# Grouping by two words using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have the following string array:

```
string[] words = new [] { "Stanford", "University", "in", "Palo", "Alto" };
```

I'd like to get the following:

```
["Stanford University", "University in", "in Palo", "Palo Alto"]
```

I know I'd probably need to use the `Aggregate` extension method but I'm not really sure how.

Comment: I would not use LINQ for that considering you will have real-size texts rather than simple string. Just loop from start till end, find words boundaries, and keep last word to return with current - simple, O(1), no big memory costs in case of yield reeturns etc

Comment: brings to mind the [following story](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-nasa-spen/). I'm with Lanorkin ... [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: FSharp has a `Seq.pairwise` method (part of it's `Seq` module, that iterates through the data in a pairwise fashion.  I believe you can import and use this from C# just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way using LINQ :

```
words.Take(words.Length-1).Select((v,i) => $"{v} {words[i+1]}").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you still want LINQ...

```
Enumerable.Range(0, words.Length - 1).Select(i => words[i] + ' ' + words[i + 1]).ToArray();
```